# Pass enum data to MATLAB from python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to invoke MATLAB functions from my python Script  and one of the matlab script takes enum parameter.

++++++++   MATLAB side   ++++++++++++++

Enum definition

```
classdef eCharCents
    enumeration
        vQs1,vQv1,vQs2,vQv2     
    end 
end
```

This is how I run the MATLAB function

```
testFunction(eCharCents.vQv2)
```

++++++++   Python Equivalent   ++++++++++++++

This is how I

```
import matlab.engine as MAT_ENG
from enum import Enum

class eCharCents(Enum):
     vQs1,vQv1,vQs2,vQv2 = range(0,4)  # I had to add range here as python needs data and value

print(eCharCents.vQs1)    # this outputs eCharCents.vQs1 

eng = MAT_ENG.start_matlab()
eng.testFunction(eCharCents.vQv2)   #  throws an error saying unsupported Data type
```

Please let me know if there is any workaround solution/comments/suggestions

MATLAB documentation doesn't specify anything about ENUM

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html#bui0jkn

Comment: I think you want `eCharCents.vQv2.value` which outputs `2`, and is an `int`

Comment: I dont need a value.  MATLAB doesn't have a requirement that enum must be associated with value.. If you check the MATLAB enum class implementation... it doesn't have value..  Inside the testFunction.m , I am comparing enum types    like  eCharCents.vQv2 == ip1  returns True   if function input ip1 is eCharCents.vQv2

Comment: Since python doesn't let me declare enum without a value, I had to write range(0,4)

Comment: Matlab might not have a requirement for this, but the current implementation of Python's enum is built on top of `OrderedDict`, which requires *both* a key and a value. This could be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), can you give a bit more clarity surrounding what this python enum is accomplishing?

Comment: Did you try using `eng.eCharCents.vQv2`? I don't see how passing a Python enum to MATLAB would be useful, you need to pass a MATLAB object.